# "%TYPE" in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, types

In Oracle, `%TYPE` is used to refer datatype of a column in a table. Is there any equivalent functionality in Azure SQL Database (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8)?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no equivalent. The closest method is to create a user-defined data type and use that for tables and variables.

Comment: Yes, We agree with Dan Guzman, there isn't an equivalent functionality in Azure SQL Database

Comment: Hi @Iniyavan, If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure SQL database(Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8), there isn't an equivalent functionality for `%TYPE` for now.

The closest method is to create a user-defined data type and use that for tables and variables.

HTH.